# Bitcoins send out after syncing wallet

Tags: transactions

Good day,

can someone maybe help me.
I just opened my wallet today after I exported it to a private key and incrypted it (Multibit wallet) and more than half of my coins has been send out to an address I dnt know. According to what I can see in the transaction History of this transfer it has been used as transaction fees for someone els`s transfer of coins.
Can this be a problem on the blockchain side or was my wallet hacked.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Your coins were stolen. See the linked question.

Comment: I sort off understand what is said there but I have no outgoing transactions that I did or do, it was only incoming on that wallet. :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are checking the balance using MultiBit perhaps your missing coins are sitting in a change address - when you send bitcoin often some coins are moved to a newly generated change address, so you would need to export more than just the one address.

Fire up bitcoincore again and check the other receive addresses in a blockchain explorer for balances.